# Getting adjacency matrix from random graph in Python

Tags: python, networkx

The following code generates a random graph. How do I obtain adjacency matrix for each graph?

```
import networkx as nx

n = 10
p = 0.9

G = nx.generators.random_graphs.gnp_random_graph(n, p)
nx.draw(G)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html):

```
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
A.toarray()
```