# How to get adjacency matrix form small world model?

Tags: python, matrix, networkx

How do I create  adjacency matrix and how can I make the connections as I want form this code?(I mean if I change the adjacency matrix, connection should change )

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(n = 10, m = 4, p = 0.5)
pos = nx.circular_layout()

plt.figure(figsize = (12, 12))
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos)
```

Comment: In the current version of networkx, the second argument of `nx.watts_strogatz_graphs()` should be `k`, not `m`.  Also, you need to pass the graph `G` to `nx.circular_layout()` for it to generate positions.   Finally to answer your two questions, here is a thread on [creating adjacency matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71809574/getting-adjacency-matrix-from-random-graph-in-python) and here is one on [adding edges to a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141812/add-edges-using-networkx).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add edges using networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141812/add-edges-using-networkx)

Comment: I will just give adjacency matrix it has to give graph in circular layout